# Enter Key simulate click not working for checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have copied and slightly modified the code found at the bottom of [this post](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/65581-use-tab-return-go-one-activex-box-next.html#post3985103) to allow tabbing between form controls on a worksheet form I have created. Here is the segment relating to the KeyCode = vbKeyEnter:

```
Select Case KeyCode
Case vbKeyTab
    Dim Backward As Boolean
    Backward = (Shift And fmShiftMask)

    Call MoveFocus(Cntrl:=Cntrl, TabIndex:=TabIndex, Backward:=Backward)

Case vbKeyEnter
    Select Case TypeName(Cntrl)
    Case TxtBoxType
        If Not (Cntrl.EnterKeyBehavior And Cntrl.MultiLine) Then
            Call MoveFocus(Cntrl:=Cntrl, TabIndex:=TabIndex)
        End If
    Case Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.Run Sheet1.CodeName & "." & Cntrl.name & "_Click"
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Select
End Select
```

The code works fine for tabbing forward and backward between controls. However, I'm having troubles using the enter key to check and uncheck check box controls. It works for option buttons, but does not work check boxes. If I add `CheckBox1.Value = True` to the CheckBox1_Click event it works to check it true, but naturally won't allow it to uncheck to false. I've tried adding the following IF statement to set it to true or false depending on current value, but then nothing happens.

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    CheckBox1.Value = False
Else
    CheckBox1.Value = True
End If
```

Another note: When I hit enter and nothing happens to the form control it moves the active cell down the active column. Any suggestions?

Comment: The spacebar has always been the accepted method of toggling a checkbox. Why are you trying to rewrite the Windows GUI system?

Comment: I guess I didn't know the spacebar was the checkbox toggle (still a little green at this). Also, the person I'm creating the form for requested it - uses left hand to tab and right hand on the number pad to key numbers/enter. I'll make sure spacebar is working for me and ask if that will suffice for him. If not, is there a way to make it work with enter?Thanks for the help, Jeeped.

Comment: `If KeyCode = 13 Then CheckBox1.Value = Not CheckBox1.Value` worked as wanted...

Comment: Sounds to me it'd be a lot easier to build a userform to handle this data entry task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> <sup>This may or may not be an answer to the programming question; I will let the voters decide.</sup>
> Q. Enter Key simulate click not working for checkboxes

Why would you do such a thing? You are spending time and effort to intentionally 'break' a working system. The <kbd>spacebar</kbd> has long been the accepted keystroke for toggling a checkbox on and off, <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> are used for navigating between form controls and <kbd>Enter↵</kbd> is the default for <kbd>OK</kbd>.

By 'working system' I mean the whole Mac/Windows/Linux GUI system and the millions of people that have trained to work within long defined standard practises. You can take the mouse away from any competent office worker and their productivity will not suffer. They can navigate through the system and applications to perform their work because everything in the system from setting the video resolution to typing workers' timecard data into a custom form **works the same way**.

Take a Windows user and stick them in front of their first Mac. They can use the programs and get the job done because the vast majority of operations (and particularly the ones for basic operation of an application) are the same. Take a Mac user and stick them in front of a Linux machine and you will get the same results. The basic day-to-day operation of the machine and its programs are the same.

What is the point of any prospective applicant looking for employment to come with a CV filled with office experience if you are going to create a proprietary system that takes all of their training, practise and experience and throws it out the window?

The use of the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> to toggle a checkbox on and off predates Windows 3.0. There is a difference between building a better mousetrap and reinventing the wheel¹.

---

¹ <sub>If you don't think that maintaining GUI standards is something to strive for, consider the backlash that the Office 2007 ribbon created. An entire sub-industry dedicated to producing add-ons that brought back Office 2003 functionality was spawned.</sub>

Comment: I don't disagree with you and plan to move forward with letting the spacebar work its magic. Had I known spacebar was the standard I wouldn't have posed the question. I've never had formal excel training and never noticed it I guess. Probably not worth the time dissecting, but at this point I'm just a little curious why it doesn't work if the code if set up to simulate a click and a click does work. Could it be the same internal processes that allow spacebar to work are setup to block this to maintain their design intent?

Comment: tbh, I haven't really looked hard at the code you provided but for all intents and purposes, you **can** redirect absolutely anything if you want to badly enough; even if you have to get all the way down to intercepting the messages going through the Windows kernel message pump. The [tab] and [shift]+[tab] navigation should be built-in. If it isn't working correctly then you need to modify the Z-order that the form controls are in. I might take a look at this later as an intellectual exercise but I need time to construct a 'test bench' userform which I do not have at the moment.

Comment: One note that has proven to be key is that the form controls are directly on a worksheet and not within a userform or frame. I learned after the fact that putting them within a frame might have allowed me to set the tab index order. However, I already had it all in place with over 60 controls and tried to find a way around rebuilding the whole form in a frame.

Comment: For programming the form controls' z-order see [What order does a For Each Next loop through my checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751515/what-order-does-a-for-each-next-loop-through-my-checkboxes/34752097#34752097). Read carefully, it is backwards to what you might expect.