# select checkbox with enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, checkbox

I have a few checkboxes that I need to be selected with the enter key instead of the space bar when it has focus. I have the code below that works for one check box, but I need multiple checkboxes. I know the id tag needs to be unique, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mycheckbox').on('keypress', function (event) {
        if (event.which === 13) {
            this.checked = !this.checked;
        }
    });
});

<input type="checkbox" name="Colors" value="Bike" id="mycheckbox">My text<br>
```

I'm trying to get this to work on all the checkboxes not just the one with the mycheckbox id.

Here's my full code so far:

`

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-

latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').on('keypress', function (event) {
        if (event.which === 13) {
            $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).prop('checked'));
        }
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<script 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></

script>
<textarea class="textfield" id="form1" name="form1">My text 

here</textarea>
<div class="taglist">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 1">Value 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 2">Value 2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 3">Value 3</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 4">Value 4</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value 5">Value 5</label>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateTextArea() {
  var allVals = $('#form1').data('initialVal'),
      lineCount = 1;
  $('.taglist :checked').each(function(i) {
    allVals+= (i != 0 || allVals.length > 0 ? "\r\n" : "") + $(this).val

();
    lineCount++;
  });
  $('#form1').val(allVals).attr('rows', lineCount);

}
$(function() {
  $('.taglist input').click(updateTextArea);

  $('#form1').data('initialVal', $('#form1').val());
  updateTextArea();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Please post the HTML that you are using.

Comment: @Greg - You are updating the textarea when a checkbox is clicked. Better to use the `change` event, like this `$('.taglist input').change(updateTextArea);`. Then trigger the change event right after you programmatically check a box, by calling `$(this).change();`.

Comment: Fantastic that works great. I appreciate everybody's time with this. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Just notice that you can select checkbox with Space 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35423812/1343917

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are trying to get this to work on all checkboxes? In that case use `$( ":checkbox" )` instead of `$('#mycheckbox')`

Comment: That got it. Thank you very much. You guys are so quick!!!! Thank you all for your help.

Comment: That got it. Thank you very much. You guys are so quick!!!! Thank you all for your help. I do have a problem though. I'm using the checkbox to send it's value to a textarea. If I click the mouse it works great. The enter key is now selecting the checkbox, but the value isn't getting passed to the textarea.

Comment: The value being the value of `checked` or the name of the checkbox?

Comment: The value of checked

Comment: @Greg, have a look at my answer.

Comment: For better performance, the [JQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) recommends you use `input:checkbox`, rather than just `:checkbox`. This is because `:checkbox` is equivalent to `*:checkbox`.

Comment: @Greg, programmatically checking a checkbox does not cause its change-event to trigger, but you can do that by calling `$(this).change();` (which is short for `$(this).trigger('change`);`. (I hope you are using the change-event and not the click-event. If not, you should switch.)

Comment: @JohnS I have edited my question to show you want I have. Not good with javascript sorry. Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `input[type="checkbox"]` or add a class to every checkbox and yes ids must be unique:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="Colors" value="Bike" id="mycheckbox1">My text<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Colors" value="Bike" id="mycheckbox2">My text<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Colors" value="Bike" id="mycheckbox3">My text<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Colors" value="Bike" id="mycheckbox4">My text
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing the selector should do the trick:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]')
```

This will return all inputs of type checkbox. Another approach is to give all the checkboxes you are interested in a class, and then match the class - I suggested this approach as well, in case you don't want to apply it to all of them. So the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="support-enter" />
```

Then the jquery selector:

```
$('.support-enter')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `classes` instead.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Colors" value="Bike" class="mycheckbox">My text<br>
```

Jquery

```
$('.mycheckbox').on('keypress', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).prop('checked'));
    }
});
```

**Another method** is to use a type `selector` in order to get the `input` elements with certain type.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]')
```

```js
$(':checkbox').on('keypress', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).prop('checked'));
        $('textarea').html($(this).prop('checked').toString());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="Colors" value="Bike" class="mycheckbox">My text<br>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but why are you creating a class when we have access to the pseudo-class selector of `:checkbox`?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use class selector instead of id selector. Just add some class to your checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**attribute-equal selector**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp) to get the inputs of type `checkbox` like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type = "checkbox"]').on('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="Colors" value="Bike">My text<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Colors" value="Bike">Other text<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    $('#mycheckbox').prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="Colors" value="Bike" id="mycheckbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code to select checkbox input with the enter Key**

```
const input = document.getElementById('tnc');

input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter" && tnc.checked == false) {
      tnc.checked = true;
  } else if(event.key === "Enter" && tnc.checked == true){
    tnc.checked = false;
  }
});
```